# Intuition behind Thompson Sampling in Reinforcement Learning

Tags: bayesian, reinforcement-learning, beta-distribution, multiarmed-bandit

**I am trying to get intuition for solving bandit problem using Thompson Sampling in Reinforcement Learning.**

I understand following:

1. Beta distribution and effect of alpha and beta params on it
2. Thompson Sampling algorithm. I am referring to algo given [here](https://github.com/lazyprogrammer/machine_learning_examples/blob/master/rl/bayesian_bandit.py)

To explain my question/thoughts, lets consider below scenario:

**Consider there are 2 bandits, one has 90% chance of wining (bandit A) and other has 90% chance of loosing (bandit B).**

1. Initially we start with uniform distribution for alpha and beta.
2. As a bandit sees more examples, it becomes skinnier and taller.
3. In every trial, we select a bandit which has higher value for **sample chosen from its beta distribution**.
4. Taller the distribution for a bandit, higher are its chances of getting selected next time.
5. Distribution would become taller **even in case when beta value increase**s i.e. we consistently loose.

**One of the below 2 might happen as a result of random selection:**

1. 'B' might get skinnier and taller hugging towards 0. (due to point 5 above)
2. 'A' might get skinnier and taller hugging towards 1.

This would imply that we are selecting B, despite of knowing the empirical evidence that there are high chances of loosing when selecting B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is some confusion in point 4. It is absolutely **not true** that the 'taller' the distribution the higher its chances of being selected.

This is because we are taking a sample from the distribution, and the height of the distribution you mention is the value of the pdf.
In your example we would sample a value $\hat{p}_b$ from the beta distribution and if it was 'skinnier and taller hugging towards 0' it would take a value of about 0.1. On the other hand sampling $\hat{p}_a$ we would get a value of about 0.9 which is clearly bigger than 0.1 meaning we will choose bandit A.

Note: $\hat{p}_a$ and $\hat{p}_b$ are clearly random so we won't always choose the right action, this is part of the beauty of Thompson sampling, but when you say the distributions are getting 'taller and skinnier' what is happening is the variance in the posterior is decreasing as we get more confident in the value of $p_a/p_b$, but that doesn't mean the expected value is high at all.

Comment: +1: Taller means more certain and more likely to get a value very close to that value. But the _value_ is what is compared in terms of which one wins.

Comment: Yes XanderJC, I actually had this confusion that from the distribution we are randomly selecting pdf value (y-axis) instead of probability (x-axis). Thanks for clarifying